# How to Interpret $P(X \in A)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with statement $S$. Consider the following subset $A \subset S$. How to I write out the probability
$$P(X \in A)$$

From my understanding, it's
$$P(X\in A)= P(\{ \omega:X(\omega)\in A\})$$
But what does this mean, and is the following true: Let $\{ \omega:X(\omega)\in A\}=\omega_1, \omega_2, ...$. Then,

$$P(X\in A)= P(\{ \omega:X(\omega)\in A\})= P(X(\omega_1)\in A, X(\omega_2) \in A, ...)$$

Comment: If a set is uncountable, you cannot list its elemnets as $\omega_1, \omega_2, ...$.

Comment: It means that, the probability that the output of $X$ belong to $A$ is $P(X\in A)$. By example, if the probability that the temperature the next day will be below 10ºC is 70% this means that its more likely the next day that the temperature would be below 10ºC, by example 9.5ºC (but of course it will be also any other number, but we expect that will be lower than 10ºC)

Comment: For example, if $X(\omega) = 1-\omega$ on $\Sigma = [0,1]$ with the uniform measure then $P[X \in [{1 \over 4}, {3 \over 4}]] = {1 \over 2}$. Draw a picture.